# Serial port worker thread freezing randomly

Tags: c#, multithreading, serial-port, backgroundworker

I am calling my background worker by the following code:

```
private void UpdateDataTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!serialPortWorker.IsBusy)
    {
        serialPortWorker.RunWorkerAsync();
    }
}
```

My `DoWork` event is as follows:

```
private void serialPortWorker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    //Configures serial port
    connection.BaudRate = 19200;
    connection.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(DataReceivedEvent);

    //Sends the commands for opening diagnostics
    string[] init_commands = { "STRING", "STRING", "STRING", "STRING", "STRING" };
    foreach (string command in init_commands)
    {
        connection.WriteLine(command + connection.NewLine);
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
    }

    const string constant_message_section = "G03";
    string[] command_list = { "62", "64", "5C" };

    //Writes all commands to all radio addresses
    foreach (int address in radioAddresses)
    {
        foreach (string command in command_list)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < MAX_ATTEMPTS; i++)
            {
                connection.WriteLine(constant_message_section + address.ToString("X4") + command);
                Thread.Sleep(500);
            }
        }
    }

    Thread.Sleep(1000); //Give a little time for all responses to come in
}
```

For some reason, after a few hundred calls of the `UpdateDataTimer_Tick` event, it will not run the `serialPortWorker` any more. I put a debugger at `if (!serialPortWorker.IsBusy)`, and it indicated that the `serialPortWorker` is still busy. It must be hanging up somewhere in the `DoWork` event, right? Any ideas why?

For those that are interested, the data received event is as follows:

```
public void DataReceivedEvent(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    SerialPort sp = (SerialPort)sender;
    string receive = sp.ReadLine();

    try
    {
        Debug.Logger.WriteToDebug("Data Received Serial Port: " + receive);
    }
    catch { }

    try
    {
        int unit_address = Int32.Parse(receive.Substring(1, 4), System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber);

        if (radioAddresses.Contains(unit_address))
        {
            int radio_index = radioAddresses.IndexOf(unit_address) + 1;
            int max_index = radio_index * 3;

            integrityMonitor[radio_index] = DateTime.Now; //Last updated time

            int message_data = 0;

            if (receive.Contains("66"))
            {
                //Stuff
            }
            else if (receive.Contains("61"))
            {
                //Stuff
            }
            else if (receive.Contains("55"))
            {
                //Stuff
            }
        }
    }
    catch { }
}
```

Comment: There's no scenario where adding a DataReceived event handler over and over again is going to come to a good end.

Comment: `connection.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(DataReceivedEvent);` concerns me. Are you ever removing these handlers?

Comment: Maybe it's insignificant, but for each call to DoWork(), you're adding an event handler to connection.DataReceived, but you're not removing it. Can you post the code for DataReceivedEvent() as well?

Comment: That might be a problem! I dont know why I did that. Would that cause this kind of behavior?

Comment: Well, yes it could definitely be a problem if this line calls your event:                         `connection.WriteLine(constant_message_section + address.ToString("X4") + command);` You're going to have a LOT of people processing that event synchronously.

Comment: Yes, each time I send that the radio would respond. This makes a lot more sense now. I have included `connection.DataReceived -= new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(DataReceivedEvent);` at the end of the function now. Feel free to post this as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, since nobody has left an answer, I will. The issue was the line

```
connection.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(DataReceivedEvent);
```

being called during every tick of the timer in background worker. This would cause numerous instances of the event handler, which would eventually cause the background worker to lock up and report busy all the time. To correct this problem, I needed to put in

```
connection.DataReceived -= new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(DataReceivedEvent);
```

in order to avoid having numerous event handlers processing the data received event. This has resolved my problem.